# How to avoid a "duplicate key" error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, concurrency

This statement:

```
INSERT INTO deleteme
SELECT #t.id, 'test' FROM #t
LEFT JOIN  deleteme  ON deleteme.id = #t.id
WHERE deleteme.id IS NULL;
```

...will fail with a primary key violation in the concurrent scenario (i.e. when inserting the same key that is absent in deleteme from several threads at the same time) with the default transaction isolation level of `READ COMMITTED`:

> Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DeleteMe'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.deleteme'.

What is the best way to prevent that?

The table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeleteMe](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DeleteMe] PRIMARY KEY ([id] ASC));
```

**Update**

From comments:

> Why do you have multiple sessions, which can obviously pull the same id from somewhere, using the same permanent table without having some kind of session key to tell them apart? Even without a duplicate error, how are you going to know which rows belong to which session?

This is a stored procedure that is called by an external service that populates data in this table. The service generates the record id and it provides no guarantee that it won't send the same data twice. Or send the same data at the same time.

The database code is supposed to discard all the records with the same id, if one already exists. The service never sends two records with the same id in the same batch.

Comment: `#t` must have duplicates at least across sessions.  If you have two sessions that are both trying to insert the same primary key value at the same time, one of them will have to get an error.  If you want to prevent the error, you'd have to prevent two sessions from trying to insert the same primary key value at the same time.  In this case, that would mean ensuring that whatever populates `#t` populates a different set of rows in each session.

Comment: @JustinCave - That's why I said "at least across sessions".  No one session may see duplicate rows in the temporary table.  But they have to be there in the underlying data structure.

Comment: Your update seems to indicate that you shouldn't be trying to prevent the duplicate key error.  The duplicate key error is an expected condition given your description of the calling service.  Your procedure needs to expect this error, catch it, and handle it.  I would guess that you simply want to catch the error and retry the operation potentially with a small delay to give the other session time to commit.

Comment: @JustinCave, that might work, feel free to post as an answer, any sample code how to re-try would be appreciated. Do you think that catching the error and retrying is the best approach? I do not find it in the wild often.

Comment: @JustinCave I think the point is that an error rejects the whole batch. Ideally, the operation would process all valid entries, silently rejecting any duplicates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really need to run multiple threads at the same time you can enable the `ignore_dup_key` option on the primary key.

This will just give a warning instead of an error when an insert would result in a duplicate key violation. But instead of failing it will discard the row(s) that if inserted would cause the uniqueness violation.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeleteMe](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Value] [varchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DeleteMe] 
PRIMARY KEY ([id] ASC) 
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON));
```

[Example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e122c/3)

[Paul White's detailed explanation on the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404165346/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/01/a-creative-use-of-ignore-dup-key.aspx). Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the table `DeleteMe` suggests that you are accumulating IDs into this table and then periodically delete rows with these IDs from some other permanent table. Is it true?

If it is true, then you can allow `DeleteMe` to have duplicate IDs. Just have a non-unique index on `id` instead of unique (and since `id` is `uniqueidentifier` it makes sense to make this index non-clustered as well):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeleteMe](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](max) NULL,
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[DeleteMe]
(
    [id] ASC
)
```

If you use `DeleteMe` to remove rows from another `MainTable` like this, then it doesn't matter if `id` in `DeleteMe` is unique or not:

```
DELETE FROM MainTable
WHERE MainTable.ID IN (SELECT id FROM DeleteMe)
```

BTW, the query to populate `DeleteMe` becomes much simpler as well:

```
INSERT INTO DeleteMe (id, Value)
SELECT #t.id, 'test' 
FROM #t
```

Comment: At first I couldn't understand what the downvote was for, but it has now occurred to me that the reason could be this part of the question: *"The service generates the record id…"* If the service generates the ID, it's unlikely the ID will be used the way your answer assumes.

Comment: @AndriyM, Somebody decided to downvote all my questions on SO and this answer today... As for this question, it is not really clear what is the ultimate goal. If you really need to filter out duplicates, then good solution should be [`IGNORE_DUP_KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186869.aspx) as Aaron said - I tried to find this hint in docs earlier, but couldn't because it is not in the section with table/query hints, but it's an index option. But, it may be OK to store duplicate `IDs`, it depends on how they are used later.